# Use my own jupyter notebook (with specific dependencies) with docker?

Tags: python, docker, file, github, jupyter-notebook

I am a docker noob, I have developed a Python script using Jupiter notebook for my master's thesis. The notebooks runes a code that gives me a forecast for sales for a specific company.

My professor wants to use and test and see my code. He told me and I quote

"put your code (not the training data) into a private GitHub repository and add a docker file (with Python in the correct version and dependencies) so I can run your code. Same for Jupyter notebooks. Github also has support for rendering Jupyter notebooks - just as fallback"

I have tried to do a Docker file, but I can't seem to understand how he will be able to access my notebook? I have uploaded my notebook on Github already as he said.

Can someone explain how can I do whatever he is asking me for?

Comment: If you're not using Docker for development, ask your professor if he really wants to run your code, or just view it.

Comment: I guess he only wants to view it since he said that I should not upload the training data.

Comment: Then send him a link to your notebook in GitHub and ask if that's what he needs